# unauthorized_client error getting access_token in nodejs (googleapis)

Tags: node.js, authorization, google-oauth, access-token

I've spent a lot of hours with this and could not find out what I am doing wrong with this.

I have a client-server web app (javascript in client, node in server). In the server I use googleapis.
I want the user to authenticate with Google Oauth2 in the Client, and then, send the authorization code to the server, get the access_token (or refresh_token), and then make some calls to google APIs (by now it will create or delete calendars to the user's account).

I get an error when trying to get my access_token in the back end.

In the front end I have this call:

```
var SCOPE_STRING = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created";
if(nouUsuari.hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE_STRING)) {
  console.log("hasGrantedScopes.");
} else {
  nouUsuari.grantOfflineAccess({
    scope: SCOPE_STRING
  })
  .then(function(resp){
    var authCode = resp.code;
    //I send here authCode to the backEnd
    self.guardarTokens(authCode);
  })
}
```

In the back end, I'm stuck at getting my acces_token, whith this call:

`var response = await self.oAuth2Client.getToken(authCodeFromFrontEnd)`

I always get the following error:

```
{
   "error": "unauthorized_client",
   "error_description": "Unauthorized"
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated as I don't know how to follow with this.

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: client side javascript isnt going to return a refresh token.  Top tip code is an authorization code not an access token.  Your mixing things

Comment: Yes, you are right. I get an authorization code in the client side. Then in the back end I'm trying to use this code to get an access_token with getToken function. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Your doing it wrong your not suposed to be mixing things like this.  Either use client side or server side dont try to use both.  Pick one

Comment: mmmmm I would really like to make all api calls in the back end. But once user has authenticated, when redirected to a URI I cannot reach the exact point of my SPA and finally get to the root URL. That's why I put the authentication in the front. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: then send the access token to the backend but once it expires the user is going to have to login again your only going to have an hour  tip calls to the api are sent using an authorization header of type bearer.  i doubt you will be able to feed the access token directly to googleapis package its designed to handle the auth itself not be loaded with existing access token.   its an interesting use case i may have to think on this one.

Comment: and is it possible to get refresh_token in the front and send it to the back so it refreshes token any time it is needed?

Comment: Because I already tried this and could not get a refresh_token to send to the back end

Comment: thats because client sided applications don't support refresh tokens its a security risk.  you need a server sided language to get a refresh token.

Comment: oh, ok thanks, good to know. I'm not sure having only an hour before user have to login again is acceptable in the app i'm working with :(

Comment: But then, if refresh_token is only available in the back end, if I make all the API calls also in the front (so that everything is in the front), the final user will have to authenticate after an hour? could I store any credentials into the database so that there is no need to authenticate so often?